# CruiseControl.Net Deleted Files

Tags: cruisecontrol.net, visual-sourcesafe

I'm using CC.net on against a Source Safe database, and have a problem that someone deleted some files from the database, and the deleted files weren't removed. I didn't see a config switch or anything that I could set for it to clear the code directory prior to building.

Am I missing something?

Comment: umm the answer you accepted is wrong..sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Alex says there is a CleanCopy flag in the source code block. However, my situation was a little different. I use subversion and I found the CleanCopy flag was NOT doing what it said it would on the box.

To solve the problem I added a task which runs a batch file that clears out the build's working copy prior to checkout. It is a bit slower (about 1 min for code base of 400Mb) but guarantees no old code.

Kindness,

Dan

Comment: How does this work with the existing SourceControl Block? Where do I stick the executable block so that the it happens between the source control check for mods and the get?

Comment: I was unable to get it to happen between the check for mods and the get. I have cruise control set to only build on mods so I did prior to the SourceControl block.

Comment: use the CleanCopy flag instead, why reinvent the wheel?

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is set CleanCopy to true in your source control block. The documentation is very clear on this. The above answer is the wrong way.

Comment: If your buildserver is building an IIS hosted website (we have integration tests that require this) Some files can not be deleted by the CleanCopy flag. Hence, I went the way I did. I don't feel the answer is wrong but I agree with your point, I should have mentioned CleanCopy (which I have now done)